# Does UILabel have any value to make it selectable?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

Does `UILabel` have any value that can be set in order to make it selectable?

I have a label that I want to be selectable, (long press and a copy btn shows up) kinda like in Safari.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you need to implement a UIMenuController from a long press gesture applied to your UILabel. There is an excellent article about this on [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uimenucontroller/), but the gist of the article is the following.

Create a subclass of UILabel and implement the following methods:

```
override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return (action == "copy:")
}

// MARK: - UIResponderStandardEditActions

override func copy(sender: AnyObject?) {
    UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = text
}
```

Then in your view controller, you can add a long press gesture to your label:

```
let gestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleLongPressGesture:")
label.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

and handle the long press with this method:

```
func handleLongPressGesture(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
     if let recognizerView = recognizer.view,
         recognizerSuperView = recognizerView.superview
     {
         let menuController = UIMenuController.sharedMenuController()
         menuController.setTargetRect(recognizerView.frame, inView: recognizerSuperView)
         menuController.setMenuVisible(true, animated:true)
         recognizerView.becomeFirstResponder()
     }}
```

NOTE: This code is taken directly from the NSHipster article, I am just including it here for SO compliance.

Comment: You also need to enable user interactions on the label. Without that the gesture will never be recognized. And it's also important to check the gesture's state in the `handleLongPressGesture` method. That NSHipster article is doing a terrible job by not doing that properly.

Comment: Hi! I had to move `recognizerView.becomeFirstResponder()` before `menuController.setMenuVisible` to have the first long press working

Answer (score 13):

### Self-contained Solution (Swift 5)

You can adapt the solution from @BJHSolutions and NSHipster to make the following self-contained `SelectableLabel`:

```
import UIKit

/// Label that allows selection with long-press gesture, e.g. for copy-paste.
class SelectableLabel: UILabel {
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        addGestureRecognizer(
            UILongPressGestureRecognizer(
                target: self,
                action: #selector(handleLongPress(_:))
            )
        )
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return action == #selector(copy(_:))
    }

    // MARK: - UIResponderStandardEditActions
    
    override func copy(_ sender: Any?) {
        UIPasteboard.general.string = text
    }
    
    // MARK: - Long-press Handler
    
    @objc func handleLongPress(_ recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if recognizer.state == .began,
            let recognizerView = recognizer.view,
            let recognizerSuperview = recognizerView.superview {
            recognizerView.becomeFirstResponder()
            UIMenuController.shared.setTargetRect(recognizerView.frame, in: recognizerSuperview)
            UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(true, animated:true)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: If you want the action to float centered above the text:

```
let textWidth = sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).width
let adjusted = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: recognizerView.frame.midY, width: textWidth, height: recognizerView.frame.height)
            UIMenuController.shared.setTargetRect(adjusted, in: recognizerSuperview)
```

Comment: Hi! I had to move `recognizerView.becomeFirstResponder()` before `menuController.setMenuVisible` to have the first long press working

Answer (score 0):

UILabel inherits from UIView so you can just add a long press gesture recognizer to the label.  Note that you have to change isUserInteractionEnabled to true, because it defaults to false for labels.

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        let label = UILabel()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            view.addSubview(label)
            label.text = "hello"
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
            let longPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressLabel(longPressGestureRecognizer:)))
            label.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGestureRecognizer)
            label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }

        @objc private func longPressLabel (longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
            if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == .began {
                print("long press began")
            } else if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
                print("long press ended")
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I've implemented a `UILabel` subclass that provides all of the functionality needed. Note that if you're using this with interface builder, you'll need to adjust the `init` methods.

```
/// A label that can be copied.
class CopyableLabel: UILabel
{
    // MARK: - Initialisation

    /// Creates a new label.
    init()
    {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        let gestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPressGesture(_:)))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: - Responder chain

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool
    {
        return true
    }

    // MARK: - Actions

    /// Method called when a long press is triggered.
    func handleLongPressGesture(_ gestuerRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
    {
        guard let superview = self.superview else { return }

        let menuController = UIMenuController.shared
        menuController.setTargetRect(self.frame, in: superview)
        menuController.setMenuVisible(true, animated:true)
        self.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    override func copy(_ sender: Any?)
    {
        UIPasteboard.general.string = self.text
    }
}
```